# I'm having trouble passing a variable from one class function to another class function in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to Python and I'm probably over complicating this.  I have it working without using a class, but I'm trying to learn as much as I can about Python.  I'm trying to access a variable from one function within another function in the same class.  My code will display various items in the PyCharm console, how do I get those items into my GUI?  Here's my entire code:

```
# Python version 3.5.1
# pyVISA version 1.8
# Collect measurement data from an Agilent U2001A USB Power Sensor

from tkinter import *  # tkinter is for setting up a GUI
from tkinter import ttk
import visa  # Import the Python VISA module


class agilentU2001A(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):  # Initialize the frame
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        rm = visa.ResourceManager()
        ports = rm.list_resources()
        self.sensor = rm.open_resource(ports[0])
        print(self.sensor)
        self.grid()
        self.sensorID()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):  # Create the labels and buttons
        # Create connected instrument labels
        self.label1 = Label(self, text="Connected sensor: ")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.instrumentLabel = Label(self, text="sensor_name")
        self.instrumentLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        # Create measurement labels
        self.label2 = Label(self, text="Measurement: ")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E, pady=10)
        self.measurementLabel = Label(self, text="numbers")
        self.measurementLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

        # Create measurement button
        self.measureButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Take Measurement!", command=self.measurement)
        self.measureButton.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=25)

        # Create exit button
        self.exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.exit_measurement)
        self.exitButton.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=25, pady=25)

    def sensorID(self):  # Get the ID from the connected sensor
        self.sensor.write("*IDN?")  # Query the instrument ID
        sensor_init = self.sensor.read()
        print("Sensor ID -> " + sensor_init)

    def exit_measurement(self):  # Close the VISA connection and program
        self.sensor.close()  # Close the connection
        sys.exit()

    def measurement(self):  # Take a measurement
        self.sensor.write("INIT:CONT ON")  # Initiate the trigger to continuous on
        self.sensor.write("FETC?")  # Read data using the fetch command
        measure = self.sensor.read()
        print(measure)

root = Tk()
root.title("Agilent U2001A USB Power Sensor")

app = agilentU2001A(root)

w = 485  # set width of window
h = 180  # set height of window
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()  # get current screen width
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()  # get current screen height
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)  # calculate x coordinate for window
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)  # calculate y coordinate for window

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))  # center window on screen

root.mainloop()  # Constantly checks for input
```

Comment: For nomenclature's sake: Functions within in a Class are called Methods. What variable are you trying to pass? What two Methods are involved?

Comment: You can create a `Label` with initially empty text, and then later in `sensorID()` method something like `self.sensor_idn_label.configure(text=sensor_init)`

Comment: You can have the method return a value if it is being called inside the other method or assign the value to a self variable `self.var = value` and then use `self.var` to get the value.

Comment: I need to pass measure from measurement to the measurementLable and sensor_init from sensorID to instrumentLabel.

Comment: Thank you very much guys.  I was able to get it working with your help.